# Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\pi^{6k}}{6k!}$

Tags: summation, power-series

Evaluate

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{\pi^{6k}}{(6k)!}$$

I was trying to find a closed form for this sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^{6k}}{(6k)!}$$

I believe there is something to do with $$\cos(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k}\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}$$

I do not have a clear idea where to started. I am wondering if someone would be able help me out !

Comment: You've written down the series for sine, not cosine.

Comment: Remember that $\left(a^b\right)^c = a^{bc}$. Therefore $\left(\pi^3\right)^{2k} = \pi^{6k}$.

Comment: Maybe you're looking at a general expansion of $cos(x^3)$

Comment: @ShreyAryan And maybe not, as writing down the expansion of $\cos(x^3)$ shows.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\omega=\exp\frac{2\pi i}{3}$. Notice that $1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}$ equals $3$ if $3\mid n$ and zero if $3\nmid n$. Deduce that

$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k x^{6k}}{(6k)!}=\sum_{3\mid k}\frac{(-1)^k x^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\frac{\cos(x)+\cos(\omega x)+\cos(\omega^2 x)}{3}.\tag{1}$$
Evaluate both sides at $x=\pi $ to get
$$ \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^k x^{6k}}{(6k)!}=-\frac{1}{3},\tag{2}$$
profit.

Comment: very clear solution  (+1)

Comment: Stupid question: What is the notation $3|k$ for?

Comment: @FourierTransform: $3\mid k$ means "$3$ divides $k$", i.e. the sum is carried on over all the $k\geq 0$ that are multiples of $3$.

Comment: @+1 and mini upvote and thank you!!

Comment: would you explain how did you come up with $1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}$ equals $3$

Comment: @ADAM: what is to explain? Compute $\chi(n)=1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}$ for some values of $n$ and check it equals three only if $n$ is a multiple of $3$ (it obviously is a $3$-periodic function). That is granted by the DFT (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), for instance.

Comment: I have been asked to make up my own infinite sum smiler to the one that I posted! Any idea how it would look like! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This series is not a simple function. Indeed the general series for $x$ gives:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{+\infty} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{x^{6k}}{(6k)!} = 1-\, _0F_5\left(\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{5}{6};-\frac{x^6}{46656}\right)$$

Namely is an HyperGeometric Function.

In you case, though, the sum is simply

$$\frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: I do not agree. By the discrete Fourier transform, the LHS **is** a simple function.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I would be honoured if you showed me the whole process. It's since lots of time I wanted to see some application of the FFT! 

In any case, I remember that function (well not that one really, but a more general one) tabulated in a book of functions, and unless I misread, I remembered it was so! Correct me of course!

Comment: It is not the Fast Fourier Transform, it is the Discrete Fourier transform, whose principle entirely lies in the first line of my proof. The characteristic function of the integers $n\equiv 0\pmod{k}$ can be written in terms of a combination of $n$-th powers of $k$-th roots of unity.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

Comment: Sorry, I meant DFT of course! -.- Typo!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Oh by the way, I just checked with Matematica, and it gives me my same result. Do you believe it's a bug?

Comment: No bug, just use a *FullSimplify*.

Comment: Try FullSimplify[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(k = 0\), \(+\[Infinity]\)]
\*FractionBox[\(\((\(-1\))\)^\((k + 1)\)\ \[Pi]^\((6  k)\)\), \(\((6  
      k)\)!\)]\)]

Comment: @FourierTransform Nice user name. But... :-)

Comment: @Did But.... what?

Comment: But user @FourierTransform misses the fact that discrete `Fourier transform` solves this question handily.

Comment: @Did lol. Yes it's funny. But in my defense, we never faced FFT or DFT that much. So I'm just a normal FT expert xD